# Manually insert a plugin on Cordova/PhoneGap Project

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm working on this project for three main platforms: iOS, Android and Windows Phone which uses OS and devices features (such as camera, barcode scanner. Also Google Plus and Facebook Auth APIs).
the structure of my project is as follow:

```
-/frontend (main frontend directory)
-+/www (HTML-JS-CSS)
--+/css
--+/img
--+/js
--+/src
-->*.html (App screens)
-->config.xml (Cordova/Phonegap xml)
```

Until now I have added plugins through config.xml and build.phonegap cares about insert it on my project, during it builds. Plugins used until now are only iOS and Android compatible (facebookconnect and Barcode Scanner). The only plugin all-OS compatible is inAppBrowser and is working good.

I have tested all iOS and Android devices and everything works perfect as expected.

However, I am having lot of trouble to make it work on Windows Phone. I know that those two plugins are not compatible with WP8, however I've found two compatibles, which are:
[BarcodeScannerWP8](https://github.com/bloxlab/BarcodeScannerWP8)
[com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect.wp8](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect.wp8)

The problem is, I don't know where to put the files (manually insert them), since I am not familiarized with this method, based on my Cordova project structure. I have read to insert plugins directory (don't know where) and native files (also don't know where). I also read about Platform directory but I don't understand this directory. Also, cordova doesn't have an online build, like PhoneGap.
I never build locally because I am building on linux, I have no Windows Phone SDK/.NET neither Xcode/iOS SDK installed on my system. So, I need to push it through PhoneGap build

I would appreciate a detailed explanation about PhoneGap/Cordova directories and files structures, regarding manually inserted plugins to be build using online Phonegap Build.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot manually add third-party plugins to a project through PhoneGap Build.

Plugins have to be packaged and submitted to PhoneGap for review and inclusion into the Build system.

In the past I have made a copy of a plugin that I needed, updated it to the PhoneGap Build spec and then submitted it. It eventually got accepted and is now available, but the process took over a month...

For now, if you need to use a third-party plugin that is not supported through the Build service, you have to build locally.

Comment: How about the PhoneGap directory and file structure? Where I have to add files (js, natives, xmls) to build locally on those three platforms: Android, iOS and Windows Phone?

Comment: If you are building locally you can use the CLI to install the plugin and do not have to manually add the plugin.